# Skyrim character progress and Steam Family Sharing

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, steam-family-sharing

I've allowed someone to try Skyrim through Family Sharing but I have one concern, when my friend plays Skyrim for the first time, will them creating a character wipe all my progress? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Possibly. *"Will I be punished for any cheating or fraud conducted by other users while playing my games?* Your Family Library Sharing privileges may be revoked and your account may also be VAC banned if your library is used by others to conduct cheating or fraud" https://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing - While Skyrim isn't VAC'd afaik, if one of the other games in your library is (which they *will have access to*) and they break the rules, your entire account is in jeopardy.

Comment: @Mazura: *Skyrim* is a single-player game (that has been modded to add multiplayer, but the odds of Valve or Bethesda caring about what happens in modded multiplayer are somewhere between zero and zero).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, it will not wipe your progress**: they will have their own local safe files (provided they are playing on their own systems).